# How to clear garbage collection in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to clear garbage collection in ruby? I configured my rails app in AWS. I have used nginx and puma manager.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does "clear garbage collection" mean?

Comment: Assuming that you want to run/start/initiate Ruby's garbage collection manually – why do you want to do that in the first place? What problem are you facing?

Comment: What does the question have to do with `rails`? If it does, then why is your (presumably) new rails application `v3` or `v4`? (Which one is it? Why is the question tagged as both? It's more likely you're using `v5` anyway.) What does the question have to do with AWS, nginx or puma?

Comment: What does "clear garbage collection" mean? And, *why are you trying to do this in the first place*? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

[`GC::start`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/GC.html#method-c-start) but in most cases (read: always) the direct call will make everything *worse*.